# Confused by AFNetworking responseObject

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

It's probably me. I'm probably doing something dumb. I'm baffled by the responseObject so have put together the simplest possible demonstration I can think of.

I want to use AFNetworking 2 in an iOS App to log in to a remote server to get an authToken.
I thought everything was working fine.
I *can* log in and get an AuthToken.

However..... if I log out and then log in as a different user I appear to get the first users responseObject and not a new one.

**I have recorded a short video demonstrating the issue**. This shows the iOS simulator, xCode debugger and web server log files all side-by-side. You can view it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0zjdsj2mor0cjq/wrongresponsobject.mp4

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log in as user1 using the demo app with the details below
2. Log in again as user2 with the details below

Each time a log in is attempted I can see the request in the server logs. 
The correct request, with the correct email and password is being posted.
The server is returning a 201 response with some response data including an authToken.

When processing the *response on the second login, the original responseObject is used and not a new one to match the new request.

I have a working demo server: 
  domain: apitest.jserve1.com/
  path-to-sign-in: /api/v1/session.json

test user accounts

user1@example.com / user1password

user2@example.com / user2password

I have a demo app which connects to this demo server that you can download here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zp62sjlb13z3g6q/WrongObjectResponseExample.zip

Am I missing something obvious? Being dumb?
If so then I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

The issue was that the app was retaining cookies from the previous login. In the end, adding the following code fixed the issue for me.

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL: networkServerAddress];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

via stackoverflow.com/questions/10984374/how-to-manage-sessions-with-afnetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a problem with the server. Make sure your user session is being cleared when you login with new credentials.

Comment: Oh my, you're absolutely correct. Thank you. Inspecting the server logs more closely I can see that the first request is hitting the database and the second isn't - instead the server is sending a response it had cached. 

Nothing wrong with AFNetworking. I was being dumb.
Thank you.